# stop ng-repeat animation from trigger at first

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

In this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/EaWEPUZ9rwT56J3cREzB?p=preview try to click add / remove, it look normal, containing a fade In animation.

But my problem is I'm using angularUI tab. So when I change tab, the whole list will fade, which I really don't like. Can I stop the animation from trigger in a function?

Comment: from the looks of it, you're using css3 animations. so when you click the tab, you have to remove the class which has an ng-enter/ng-leave animation from the html. You can't really just stop the animation with a function, but you can remove a class with a function.

Comment: @EliteOctagon once a tab is click and the class got removed, then will the list still animate when a new item is pushed?

Comment: if you remove the class then it won't animate, because the class is what ties it to the animation